# Gradle support in IntelliJ idea: empty tool window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft-forge

I've got a gradle opensource project I want to tinker with a bit.

Said project is here: https://github.com/Blood-Asp/GT5-Unofficial

When I try to import it into IntelliJ IDE it kind of works (as in - ide does it stuff reading up sources, does gradle wrapper downloads, etc) but IDEA doesn't see any gradle tasks. I --suppose-- this's like that due to lack of gradlew wrapper.

When I run `gradle <taskname>` or `gradle <tasks>` by hand in project directory, I see all the tasks and I can run them.

What can be done to allow IDEA to see the gradle tasks as well?

Answer (score 0):

did you first run the setupDecompWorkspace?

The usual process for me setting up a Gradle project in Idea for Forge is as follows

Command Line : gradlew setupDecompWorkspace

Import Gradle project into IDEA

look on the gradle view in idea for genIntellijRuns and run that within idea

Close and reopen the Project.

Program